# OpenLayers map displays on Desktop but will not display on Mobile?

Tags: openlayers, mobile, geowebcache

I have the code shown below that works perfectly on a desktop, but will only display the OSM layer on a mobile device.

Am I missing something obvious?

My understanding is that it should work on both with no adjustments.

Devices tested include IPhone, IPad and Android, with a couple of different browsers.

I am working with OpenLayers Version 3.0.0 (release version)

I know the `buffer` and `isBaseLayer` parameters may be unnecessary, trying to figure that out now in the documentation.

---

I figured out it was a tile size issue. I am using GeowebCache which expects a tile size of 256, but it is returning the following error ONLY when used on a mobile device

```
400: The requested tile dimensions 384x384 do not match those of the grid set (256x256)
```

I found this code in an obscure email thread, but it appears map.tileOrigin is undefined:

```
          tileGrid: new ol.tilegrid.TileGrid
                ({
                origin: [map.tileOrigin[0], map.tileOrigin[1]],
                resolutions: map.resolutions,
                tileSize: 256,
                }),






    // Base Map
      Mware_Layer_OSM = new ol.layer.Tile({
            title: 'OpenStreetMap',
            isBaseLayer: true,
            preload: Infinity,
            buffer: buffer,
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
      })



    // Layer Group
      Mware_Layer_PCodes = new ol.layer.Tile({
        title: 'PostCodes',
        preload: Infinity,
        buffer: buffer,
        source: new ol.source.TileWMS( ({
          urls: urls,
          params: {'LAYERS': Required_Layer, SRS:'EPSG:3857', 'TILED': true, format: 'image/' + Image_Format},
          serverType: 'geoserver',
          visible: true
        }))
      });


    // View
    view = new ol.View({
        center: transform(startLon, startLat),
        zoom: Initial_Zoom
    });

    // Create the Map
    map = new ol.Map({
        target: target_div,
        layers: [Mware_Layer_OSM, Mware_Layer_PCodes],
        renderer: 'canvas',
        view: view,
        controls: ol.control.defaults({
            attributionOptions: {
            collapsible: false
          }
        }),


    });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message means that you are using a WMS-C tile service which does not support the pixel ratio of the mobile device you were trying. To fix this, just remove the `serverType` config option of your `ol.source.TileWMS`.